# Why do locpoly and ksmooth give different results when they both supposedly do kernel regression?

Tags: r, regression, kernel-density

If you want to do kernel regression in R, you have `ksmooth` from base R and `locpoly` from KernSmooth. `locpoly` is more general, but if you pass the parameter `degree = 0`, supposedly it also gives the kernel regression, like ksmooth. Yet, the two functions give different results.

```
#install.packages("KernSmooth")
library(KernSmooth)

x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
y <- c(40, 46, 64, 93, 34, 64, 92, 94, 63)

yy1 <- ksmooth(x, y, kernel = "normal", bandwidth = 2, x.points = x)$y
# [1] 42.13168 49.31186 65.62029 72.85509 54.53128 64.40078 85.13549 86.31581 72.26733

yy2 <- locpoly(x, y, bandwidth = 2, kernel = "normal", gridsize = 9, range.x = c(1, 9), degree = 0)$y
# [2] [1] 52.64035 56.34489 60.00524 63.35969 66.67204 70.28405 73.79947 76.28162 77.17923
```

In the above, I run both functions with the same inputs, but the results are different, even though they both supposedly do a kernel regression on the data.

Comment: https://bookdown.org/egarpor/PM-UC3M/npreg-kre.html#npreg-kre-nw discusses the difference in the algorithms used between the two functions. I think the difference in the algorithms is more appropriately asked in stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @hpesoj626 that article concurs that kernel regression (what ksmooth claims to do) is the same as doing local polynomial regression with degree zero (what i'm doing with locpoly). So I think the difference lies in the implementation.